# Edge-connectivity: Does it mean to split a graph into two?

Tags: graph, computer-science

The minimum number of edges whose deletion from a graph G disconnects G.
Above is the definition of edge connectivity, does it mean G will be split into two pieces only?
or will be split into any number of pieces?

Just did not see that point, which one is right?

Answer (score 2):

Say the edge-connectivity is k. It means you need to remove at least k links to split a graph into several (separated) components. Now, remove only the k-1 first links. At this point, the graph is still connected. The removal of the kth link will split it. But a link connects only two nodes, so, if each node belongs to one different *potential* component, it connects (at most) only two *potential* components. So, removing this kth link will always split the graph into only 2 components. This is not true for node-connectivity, since a node can be attached to several links, i.e. several other nodes, i.e. more than two *potential* components.